# In this query I'm getting error

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate

In this query:

```
String sql="select  BookCategory category from LibraryBook,BookMaster,BookCategory where (LibraryBook.id="+bookid+" AND LibraryBook.BookMaster.id=BookMaster.id AND BookMaster.BookCategory.id=BookCategory.id)";
```

I'm getting error:

> unexpected token: category near line 1, column 22 [select BookCategory category from com.xtr.schoolmanager.domain.facility.library.LibraryBook ,com.xtr.schoolmanager.domain.facility.library.BookMaster,com.xtr.schoolmanager.domain.facility.library.BookCategory where (LibraryBook.id=18 AND LibraryBook.BookMaster.id=BookMaster.id AND BookMaster.BookCategory.id=BookCategory.id)]; nested exception is org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: category near line 1, column 22 [select BookCategory category from com.xtr.schoolmanager.domain.facility.library.LibraryBook ,com.xtr.schoolmanager.domain.facility.library.BookMaster,com.xtr.schoolmanager.domain.facility.library.BookCategory where (LibraryBook.id=18 AND LibraryBook.BookMaster.id=BookMaster.id AND BookMaster.BookCategory.id=BookCategory.id)]

Please help me to get a correct answer for this.

Comment: Can you show us how your entities are linked and what you want to retrieve? Your query is pretty weird to me.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem:

```
select  BookCategory category
```

I'm guessing you want to select the `category` column from `BookCategory` table? In which case it should read:

```
select  BookCategory.category
```